# Config File in NodeJS using npm config

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a on-cloud SAAS application built on Angular/NodeJS/Postgres+MongoDB stack that can connect to customer DB, cloud warehouses, S3 buckets etc to load information. Once I get the connection information from Angular front-end I need to store this information for future retrieval .

```
Example :
Angular Front-end
<form>
Database Type : 
Host : 
Port : 
Username: 
Password :

S3Bucket : 
Region :
bucket-name :
Access key :
</form>
```

etc.

I need this information saved for later access. As suggested by Abdullah Deliogullari in the original question, I am trying to use config module [npm config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config). But how do I use package config to write config file and load it in a running application.

ie While my application is running I need to write the (say S3) bucket info to a customer.config file (from frontend JSON) and later when required to retrieve data use the customer.config to connect to S3 bucket.

The "get" portion I am able to understand but the write portion (adding a new section dynamically) is what I am not able to figure out.

Example from frontend when I pass in the values like

```
 ["ct_postgres":
       {"host":"3.15.xxx.xxx", 
         "port":"5132",
         "dbname":"wcdb"     
      }]
```

this should be written to the config file. So something like config.put/write I am looking for. Next time I want to make connection to the customer postgresdb I do config.get() and it provides me the connection details.

[Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727508/best-way-to-save-customer-configuration-credentials-and-information)

Answer (score 0):

First you should install this package

```
npm install config
```

After that create config file into your project directory(name "config" is a must).
In this file create development.json and production.json files(these names are optional). Content of development.json could be like this

```
{
  "SERVER" : {
     "port" : 5000
  },

  "PASSWORDHASH" : {
    "saltRounds" : 10
  }
}
```

In your javascript file for example in app.js file, first you should include the library, and then you can get configuration informations via this module

```
const config = require('config');
const port = config.get("SERVER.port");
app.listen(port);
```

Last step should be add this development.json file name to NODE_ENV variable

```
NODE_ENV=development node app.js
```

So if you want to update your json file based on new data coming from your frontend, you can basically do this

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file_content = fs.readFileSync("development.json");
var content = JSON.parse(file_content);
content.SERVER.port = 6000;
fs.writeFileSync("development.json", JSON.stringify(content));
```

Comment: Yes the get portion I got but what I want is from frontend when I pass in the values like [ct_postgres:{"host":"3.15.xxx.xxx", "port":"5132","dbname":"wcdb"} this should be written to the config file. So something like config.put/write I am looking for. Next time I want to make connection to the customer postgresdb I do config.get() and it provides me the connection details.

Comment: I edit my answer, can you check whether this is what you are looking for or not ??

Comment: Thanks you. I was expecting a "set" call similar to the "get" to set a group of config properties like :   "db_postgres" : { host: "1.1.XXX",
     "port" : "5000" , "sid" : "wcdb" }   . Currently I am checking if keeping them in db is a better option.  Appreciate your valuable inputs.